# VBA Set = Worksheets on a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm going crazy over this one. I'm trying to filter the first column on Sheet "Detail Aging (2)", but the filter values vary with time and I'm required to not modify the Macro in the future.

I thought of pulling the filter values from a sheet in a different workbook using a range, but I can't reference the sheet in that workbook. I get "Subscript out of range".

Below is the piece of code I'm using. It works just fine when the sheet with the range is on the same workbook.

```
Dim vCrit As Variant
Dim wsO As Worksheet
Dim wsL As Worksheet
Dim rngCrit As Range
Dim rngOrders As Range
Set wsO = Worksheets("Detail Aging (2)")
Set wsL = Worksheets("C:\Users\lm733600\Desktop\Fabrizio\[Collectible Blank.xlsm]Collectors")
Set rngOrders = wsO.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion
Set rngCrit = wsL.Range("ColRange")
```

Any piece of advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Set the other workbook first then set sheet = otherworkbook.sheetyouwant

Comment: Do you have an example of that? I've tried to use Dim wb As Workbook and then setting the workbook but it throws the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a workbook object

```
Dim vCrit As Variant
Dim wsO As Worksheet
Dim wsL As Worksheet
Dim rngCrit As Range
Dim rngOrders As Range
Set wsO = Worksheets("Detail Aging (2)")

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\lm733600\Desktop\Fabrizio\Collectible Blank.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)

set wsL = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set rngOrders = wsO.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion
Set rngCrit = wsL.Range("ColRange")
```

Comment: I tried to keep the workbook closed since it's write protected and throws a prompt to enter the password. Can it be set to open as read only? And if set to read only, the macro can't continue as "Collectible Blank" is now the active workbook and Set wsO = Worksheets("Detail Aging (2)") fails to complete.

Comment: Yes you can add , ReadOnly:=True after the file path and name. See change above.  Not sure if that will prevent the password request though.  As for the set wsO issue.  set wb = .. after you set wsO. See edit above.

Comment: If it is the only file in the directory you could just look to see what file is in there. Or you could use something like this. http://analysistabs.com/vba/open-file-dialogbox-excel-macros-example-code/ so the user could browse for it.

Comment: You really saved me on this one! Your solution does it perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help you out.  Keep coding.